ssh@0 task failed to execute sql script : Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
I am using the below SSH task to execute my sql script via powershell, but the tasks failed with error:

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

The same task succeeds in primary sql node, fails only on the secondary sql node
I also tried to ssh manually from my devops agents to the secondary sql server, it's the same response.
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: 'Create Scheduled Job'
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'ssh_Server2'  # Replace with your SSH service connection name
    runOptions: 'commands'
    commands: |
      pwsh -File "$(PackagePath)\RunSQLScripts.ps1" -dbName msdb -dbServer Server2 -sqlScript "$(PackagePath)\Scripts\Create_Scheduled_Job.sql"

SSH service is running as Local System account. Only using the publicKeyAuthentication, passwordauth is disabled. Infact CopyFilesOverSSH@0 works without any issues to the same server.
Issue is only when I use ssh from agent to sql server, running the script on sql server as any user , the script executes successfully.
RunSQLScripts.ps1

    param
(
   [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Database name")]
   [string]$dbName,

   [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Database server name and instance")]
   [string]$dbServer,

   [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Path to sql script")]
   [string]$sqlScript

)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Write-Output "################## Execute SQL Script Task ##############"
Write-Output "Database Server: $dbServer"
Write-Output "Database Name: $dbName"
Write-Output "Script: $sqlScript"

try
{
    Write-Output "########## Executing Script on SQL Server - $dbServer\\$dbName,"

    invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "$sqlScript" -serverinstance "$dbServer" -database "$dbName" -TrustServerCertificate | Out-String

    Write-Output "########## Executed $sqlScript on SQL Server - $dbServer\\$dbName"
}
catch 
{
    Write-Warning -Message "########## Error while Executing SQL Script - $assemblyName from location - $assemblyPath"
    Write-Error -Message "$($_.Exception.Message)"
}

Write-Output "################## End ##############"


FYI, SQL Server 2008 reached end of life well over 5 years ago; you urgently need to upgrade to a (fully) support version (2019+) of SQL Server.

its SQL 2019, not 2008. tag was added by mistake.

This could be a double-hop issue.

Are you actually using SSIS? If so, which SSH task are you using, and what is preventing you from using something like the Execute SQL Task? If you aren't using SSIS, you should remove the tag.

You mentioned if you manually ssh from devops agent to 2nd sql server, it will have same response. But you also mentioned ssh from agent to sql server, run the script on sql server as any user, it's successful. Could you please clarify what's the difference here? Does the same command work after you manually ssh from DevOps agent to the sql server? The error comes from SQL server, which means the task is correctly started(SSH successful). It should not an issue from DevOps, but mostly your local configuration.

I mean if i manully ssh from devops agent or via devops both fails. But if the script is run locally on the sql server it works. Issue is only with SSH. Where as the same SSH works on primary sql node.

Please try to add whoami in SSH@0 task before the sql script, check the user output. Does this user have permission on the 2nd sql server? Add related role for this account on 2nd server if needed.

I found the actual issue, the issue was in the SQL script, which is referencing primary node that caused the ssh execution of sql script on secondary node to fail with 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. I found alternate way to fetch that value. Could the hop on problem.

Glad to know it's resolved! Yes it should be not a DevOps issue but double-hop issue from sql side. You can answer yourself so that more members can benefit from it. Thanks.

The error message Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' happens when authenticating with SQL server，which means the SSH connection is succesful, the command starts to run. It's not an issue from DevOps.
As confirmed, the issue was in the SQL script, which is referencing primary node that caused the ssh execution of sql script on secondary node to fail with 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. It's hop issue on SQL.
